# Uncaught ReferenceError: FontAwesomeIcon is not defined in ReactJs

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend, font-awesome, react-component

I was trying to use Font Awesome Icons in my react project (using vite), but my console throws me this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: FontAwesomeIcon is not defined
[image: Screenshot of console, It only says FontAwesomeIcon is not defined!!]

```
import React from "react";
function Skills() {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="skills">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="content">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-brands fa-html5" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Skills;
```

I got my kit code from font awesome and I pasted it in my index.html below my main.js.

I was trying to use Font Awesome Icons but it didn't work, I tried importing it using import (from another stackoverflow suggetion.) so I removed the import fontawesome! But I couldn't get it working... Please help.

Answer (score 0):

npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome

install all this packages and import the icon in your responsive Skills.js file

Comment: Did that already, didn't work, can you tell me about the import?? I tried it but didn't work...

Comment: Got this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@fortawesome_free-solid-svg-icons.js?v=e8271d61' does not provide an export named 'html5' (at Skills.jsx?t=1671185193479:18:10)  After I tried this {                                                                                                  
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { html5 } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"; }

Comment: Can I see the error image of your code?

Comment: I will edit the original query and add the image.

Comment: What is this fortawesome project we keep hearing about?